# laplace- second order

Tags: laplace-transform

We were told to solve this using the series equivalent circuit for the inductor and the parallel equivalent circuit for the capacitor. However, I am not sure how that will look like. Could someone please illustrate?

[image]

Comment: What are you solving for? (\$v_c\$?) What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what is exactly what they mean, but we use those names for the *first order equivalent models* of an inductor and a capacitor. Where usually the inductor has its series resistance (to emphasize the losses on the wire) and the capacitor has its parallel resistance (to emphasize the charge losses). But you need the merit factor (Q) or the dissipation factor (D) or the value of the parasitic resistors in order to solve the circuit.

The circuit would look like this:

[image: Schematic diagram]

You can try to solve it without defining values for resistors, get the symbolic answer and then replace with some values to see how it affects. I'd ask for more clarification of the excersise.